# Django: User can only edit or delete objects tied to their account

Tags: python, django, web-applications

There is a similar question to this, but it requires the use of tastypie - I'm looking for a way to do this without any additional add-ons.

I'm trying to create a system where users can only edit objects tied to their account.

models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

I would like a system whereby only the user specified in the author field is able to edit or delete the object. This doesn't seem (to me) to be possible using the default admin system. I could implement it by writing my own admin page which checks whether a user is authorised to delete a specific object, but It would be better if there were another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a ModelAdmin instance for your model(s) and override the appropriate methods:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    def has_add_permission(request):
        # Should return True if adding an object is permitted, False otherwise.

    def has_change_permission(request, obj=None)
        # Should return True if editing obj is permitted, False otherwise.
        # If obj is None, should return True or False to indicate whether editing of objects of this type is permitted in general 

    def has_delete_permission(request, obj=None)
        # Should return True if deleting obj is permitted, False otherwise.
        # If obj is None, should return True or False to indicate whether deleting objects of this type is permitted in general
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This has solved my problem. Not sure why I couldn't find this.

Comment: This is working for the has_change_permission but nor for has_delete_permission. It passes an object to obj for has_change, but not for has_delete. Is there a reason for this? Otherwise there is no way of telling which object is trying to be deleted and whether it is permitted.

Comment: Did you read the comment?  If it's bot passing an object, it's not trying to delete anything, it's trying to work out "whether deleting objects of this type is permitted in general"

Comment: Yes I did. It seems it's a known bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11383. When you try to delete multiple objects, it doesn't pass the individual objects. It only passes an object when you delete a single object from the edit page.

Comment: As a work around, you can disable the multi-selection actions by adding `actions = None` to your `ModelAdmin` class